# onclick function gets called when clicking link on top

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a link linking to user pages on posts, and the post itself opens a dedicated page for the post, when clicked on:
$userid = $entry['userid'];

```
$username = getUserName($userid);
$created_at = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $entry['created_at']);
echo "<div class=\"".$class."\" onclick=\"postById(".$entry['id'].")\"><p class=\"info\">Posted by <a class=\"userlink\" onclick=\"userById(".$userid.")\">".$username."</a> on ".$created_at->format('j.n.Y')." at ".$created_at->format('H:i')."</p>";
echo "<h2 class=\"title\">".$entry['title']."</h2>";
echo $entry['content']."</div>";
```

The functions:

```
function postById(postid) {
  let form = document.createElement('form');
  form.action = 'post.php'
  form.method = 'GET'
  form.innerHTML = '<input name="postid" class="hidden" value="' + postid + '">';
  document.body.append(form);
  form.submit()
}
function userById(userid) {
  let form = document.createElement('form');
  form.action = 'user.php'
  form.method = 'GET'
  form.innerHTML = '<input name="userid" class="hidden" value="' + userid + '">';
  document.body.append(form);
  form.submit()
}
```

When clicking on the post, it redirects to its page, as it should. But when clicking on the link, the post page opens anyway. `userById()` still gets called, but after `postById()`, and by my understanding breaks with the first redirect.

How can I stop the div from recognising a click when clicking the link ontop?

[Illustration of how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y99Yk.png) Green = `userById()`; orange = `postById()`

Comment: Try limiting the scope of the tag

Comment: Not quite sure if I understood what you ment, but it doesn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Function postById(postid) {
      disableOtherLinks(); //You must define it ;)
      ...
```

OR

```
var called = false;

Function postById(postid) {
     if( called ) return false;
     called = true;
     ...

Function userById(userid) {
     if( called ) return false;
     called = true;
     ...
```

Comment: Although your answer may be adequate enough to push the OP into the right direction, you might want to elaborate it.

Comment: This seems to work the wrong way arround. I want to disable the `postById()` function, which gets called first, when clicking the `userById()` function. And disableing the link won't work if the function got already called

Comment: This worked after adding an if statement to the `postById()` submit:
`if (called == false) {
    form.submit();
  }`
Could you add it to your answer to be more clear for future users?

Comment: OK. I will / your answer is right But i don't want to append form without submitting / i think this will work : `if( called ) return FALSE;`

Comment: Yes it does. Now I don't understand why it works though, could you elaborate on that? (why the other function doesn't get executed)

Comment: On click USER link => trigger **userById** and then **postById** / It makes it => always  **postById**

Answer (score 0):

Try limiting the scope of the `onClick` listener to where you want it to work

Try this

```
echo "<div class=\"".$class."\"><p class=\"info\"><a onClick=\"postById(".$entry['id'].")\">Posted by </a><a class=\"userlink\" onClick=\"userById(".$userid.")\">".$username."</a> <a onClick=\"postById(".$entry['id'].")\">on ".$created_at->format('j.n.Y')." at ".$created_at->format('H:i')."</a></p>";
```

Comment: While the post doesn't open when clicking the link anymore, I know need to click on the text to open the post, while I want the post to open when clicking anywhere on the div. I added an illustraion above for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) to suppress the click event from traveling to the parent element. [Here's an example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yrgvaj) of this in action, click the red to trigger the div, green for the link only.

So for your DOM:

```php
echo "<div class=\"".$class."\" onclick=\"postById(".$entry['id'].")\"><p class=\"info\">Posted by <a class=\"userlink\" onclick=\"userById(event, ".$userid.")\">".$username."</a> on ".$created_at->format('j.n.Y')." at ".$created_at->format('H:i')."</p>";
```

Your handling Javascript:

```
function userById(event, userid) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  let form = document.createElement('form');
  form.action = 'user.php'
  form.method = 'GET'
  form.innerHTML = '<input name="userid" class="hidden" value="' + userid + '">';
  document.body.append(form);
  form.submit()
}
```

Comment: I get at what this should do, but for some reason it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Must be something you've missed out, try put a `console.log` in the function calls and play around with `stopPropagation` till you get it right